# rake aborted! uninitialized constant Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper by using jasmine gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application Gemfile

```
gem 'jasmine', :group => [:development, :test]
```

I tried `rake jasmine` but its comes  error like

```
this.rake aborted! uninitialized constant Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this other post. You can just put it in the test group and it will not error out.

https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem/issues/150